# How to import multiple vCard VCF contact files into Outlook using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, vcf-vcard

How can I import multiple vCard VCF contact files into Outlook using Powershell ?

My script for create vcf is :

```
    # Création d'un fichier.vcf

New-Item C:\TEST\$($LastName)_$($Name).vcf -type file -force -value "
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;LANGUAGE=fr;CHARSET=utf-8:$($Agence) 
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:$($LastName), $($Name)
ORG;CHARSET=utf-8:$($Company)
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:$($Title)
TEL;WORK;VOICE:$($WorkNum)
TEL;WORK;VOICE:$($WorkNum2)
TEL;CELL;VOICE:$($MobNum)
LABEL;WORK;PREF;CHARSET=utf-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:$($WorkAdress)
X-MS-OL-DEFAULT-POSTAL-ADDRESS:1
EMAIL;CHARSET=utf-8;PREF;INTERNET:$($Email)
X-MS-IMADDRESS;CHARSET=utf-8:$($Email) 
PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:$($encodedImage)

X-MS-OL-DESIGN;CHARSET=utf-8:<card xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/outlook/12/electronicbusinesscards' ver='1.0' layout='left' bgcolor='ffffff'><img xmlns='' align='fit' area='16' use='cardpicture'/><fld xmlns='' prop='name' align='left' dir='ltr' style='b' color='000000' size='10'/><fld xmlns='' prop='org' align='left' dir='ltr' color='000000' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns=' prop='telwork' align='left' dir='ltr' color='d48d2a' size='8'><label align='right' color='626262'>Bureau</label></fld><fld xmlns='' prop='telhome' align='left' dir='ltr' color='d48d2a' size='8'><label align='right' color='626262'>Domicile</label></fld><fld xmlns='' prop='email' align='left' dir='ltr' color='d48d2a' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='addrwork' align='left' dir='ltr' color='000000' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='im' align='left' dir='ltr' color='000000' size='8'><label align='right' color='626262'>Mess. instant.</label></fld><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns=' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/><fld xmlns='' prop='blank' size='8'/></card>
END:VCARD"`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found answers at my question, so I used an other technical.

First, I created a Csv and I converted it to XLs with this Powershell code :

```
    # Creating and Adding the first line of the Csv
  $String = "FullName;CompanyName;Email1Address;Fileas;JobTitle;BusinessTelephoneNumber;Business2TelephoneNumber;MobileTelephoneNumber;BusinessAdress;PathImage"

  $PathCsv = "C:\TEST\Contacts.csv"
  $CsvExists = Test-Path $PathCsv 

 if($CsvExists -eq $True) {
     Clear-Content $PathCsv 
     Add-Content $PathCsv -value $String
 } else {
     New-Item $PathCsv -type file  -value $String   
 }

 For Each .... {

    # Storing Information in variables
  $Name = "..."
  $Last [...] 

    # Adding the information in the Csv
  $string2= "$($Name) $($LastName);$($Corp);$($Email);$($Agence);$($Title);$($NumWork);$($NumWork2);$($NumCell);$($WorkAdress);$($path)"

  Add-Content -path $PathCsv -value $string2


     # Converting Csv to Xls
  $PathXls = "C:\TEST\Contacts.xls"
  $XlsExists= Test-Path $PathXls
  $xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
  $xl.visible = $true
  $Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open($PathCsv) 
  $Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets

 if($XlsExists -eq $True) {
   Remove-Item $PathXls -force
 }  
  $Workbook.SaveAs($PathXls,1) 
  $Workbook.Saved = $True

 $xl.Quit()
 }
```

Second, I created Outlook contact with this VBScript :

```
  Sub creater()

      Dim strPath
      Dim num1 
      Dim num1toreplace 
      Dim num2 
      Dim num2toreplace 
      Dim num3 
      Dim num3toreplace 
      Dim Corp 

        Const olContactItem = 2

      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST\Contacts.xls")


       x = 2

    Do Until objExcel.Cells(x, 1).Value = ""

      Set objContact = objOutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)

      'Add FullName
       objContact.FullName = objExcel.Cells(x, 1).Value

      'Add CompanyName
       objContact.CompanyName = objExcel.Cells(x, 2).Value

      'Add Email1Address
       objContact.Email1Address = objExcel.Cells(x, 3).Value

      'Add Fileas
       objContact.Fileas = objExcel.Cells(x, 4).Value

      'Add JobTitle
       objContact.JobTitle = objExcel.Cells(x, 5).Value

      'Add BusinnesNum
       objContact.BusinessTelephoneNumber  = objExcel.Cells(x, 6).Value

      'Add BusinnesNum2
       objContact.Business2TelephoneNumber = objExcel.Cells(x, 7).Value

      'Add MobileNum
       objContact.MobileTelephoneNumber = objExcel.Cells(x, 8).Value

      'Add BusinessAddress
       objContact.BusinessAddress = objExcel.Cells(x, 9).Value

      'Add Picture
       strPath = objExcel.Cells(x, 10).Value
      If Not strPath = vbNullString Then
         objContact.AddPicture (strPath)
      End If


      objContact.Save

      x = x + 1
    Loop

      objExcel.Quit

 End Sub 
 creater()
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

I. Outlook Object Model - call [Namespace.OpenSharedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869733.aspx) (it supports MSG, vCard, and iCal formats) and pass the VCF file name. Outlook will return an instance of the [ContactItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867603.aspx) object that you can save or move to any folder.

II. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it supports vCard format (among a dozen or so other formats, vCard included) by the `Import` method (exposed by the [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) and objects derived from it, such as [RDOContactItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOContactItem.htm)).

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT 'or you can use Logon, LogonHostedExchangeMailbox, etc.
set Contact = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items.Add
Contact.Import "c:\Temp\test.vcf ", olVCard
Contact.Save
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ; I haven't "Redemption", so i would like to use the first option, but i don't understand how i can use the Object Model .OpenSharedItem to import the vcf files into Outlook ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem - Application.Session.OpenSharedItem will return the ContactItem object.

Answer (score 0):

This source could be an accepted answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73654824/3426192

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Users\$ENV:UserName\Contacts"
$ext = "vcf"
$rootName = "contact_"
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader("Contacts\MultipleContacts.vcf")
$count=1
while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
  if ($line -eq "BEGIN:VCARD")
  {
    $fileName = "{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($rootName,$count,$ext)
    ++$count
  }
  Add-Content -path $fileName -value $line
}
$reader.Close()
```

Then drag & drop into `Outlook > People > My Contacts`